# TypeScript compilation failing inside Dockerfile

Tags: typescript, docker

I have the following `Dockerfile` which is failing at the step which compiles TypeScript:

```
FROM node:12
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# SETUP

COPY package.json .
COPY tsconfig.json .
COPY src .

RUN npm install -g yarn@^1.16.0
RUN yarn install

# BUILD

RUN npx tsc <------------------------
```

The error message is very confusing:

```
File '/usr/src/app/app.ts' is not under 'rootDir' '/usr/src/app/src'. 'rootDir' is expected to contain all source files.
```

This makes no sense... It's finding `app.ts` under the `src` folder and then complaining that it isn't under the `src` folder.

Files:

```
src
  app.ts
tsconfig.json
Dockerfile
```

How do I solve this issue?

Here is my `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "outDir": "./build",
    ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wow, it was such a simple problem unrelated to TypeScript.

I didn't do the `COPY` command correctly.

When copying files you can do `COPY <filename> .`

But apparently for directories you must do `COPY <dirname> <dirname>`

So I fixed this by changing `COPY src .` to `COPY src src`.

Comment: Thanks for following up and submitting your own answer! (Don't forget to mark it as accepted once the timer runs out :) )

Comment: @msanford Yep. I still can understand why they made the `COPY` command like that though